# Why is racket passing #<void> to my function instead of the state?

Tags: racket

I'm learning Racket, and using the book Realm Of Racket. I reached the point where they show you how to animate an image moving down the window, and then suggest you try modifying it to react to a left or right-arrow key press to move the image sideways.

Seemed simple enough...

```lisp
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/universe 2htdp/image)

(define WIDTH 500)
(define DX 0)
(define HEIGHT 500)
(define IMAGE .) ; The image doesn't show up here

(define (add3-to-state current-state)
  (+ current-state 3))

(define (draw-image current-state)
  (place-image IMAGE (+ DX (/ WIDTH 2)) current-state (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT)))

(define (state-is-500 current-state)
  (>= current-state 459))

(define (set-delta current-state key)
  (set! DX (+ DX 10)))

(big-bang 0
  (on-tick add3-to-state)
  (on-key set-delta)
  (to-draw draw-image)
  (stop-when state-is-500)
  )
```

When I run this, the image moves downwards as before, but as soon as I hit a key, I get an error...

```
>=: contract violation
   expected: real?
   given: #<void>
```

...in the `state-is-500` function.

Anyone able to explain why this is happening? As far as I can see, my function for `on-key` has the same form as the ones they show in the book.

I tried modifying the `state-is-500` function to look like this...

```lisp
(define (state-is-500 current-state)
  (printf "~a\n" current-state)
  (>= current-state 459))
```

...and the output I got was...

```
102
105
#<void>
```

...before the error happened.

So it looks like `#<void>` is being passed to the function, but why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that big-bang expects the function call on-key to return the new state of the game. You are not retuning anything thus the frameworks reports `<void>`

Thus if the state does not change the you should just return the input state e.g.

```
(define (set-delta current-state key)
  current-state)
```

Also this framework and Racket itself makes you want to not mutate variables, that is you don't assign to them, or at least you assign to them only once. Thus `set!` is not something you should use often.

In this case the state of the app that the book provides is just the vertical distance so is just a single number as shown in `add3-to-state`. The original state is passed in as the first parameter to big-bang.

The change you have to make is that the current state is not just the up-down movement but also the side to side. This movement shows up as the second parameter to  `place-image`. So you have to have a state that can provide the second and third parameters to that.

Comment: Thanks very much, makes perfect sense now you explain it. As for the mutability, I know about that, and even have a comment to that effect in my code (removed along with the other comments when I posted here). However, as I'm new to Racket, I was taking it one step at a time. Now I have the sideways movement working, immutability is next! Thanks again.